# How to get the values from fields in the current row of a while loop when a button if clicked in php

Tags: php, jquery

I need help Please: How do I get the values of the fields in the row i click when the button with id of $id is clicked. I have tried the code below but when i run the script, I get only the value of the first row even if I clicked the button on the last row

```
<tbody>
                                        <?php
                                        $sn = 1;
                                        $marksheet = $_GET['id'];

                                        $query = " SELECT * FROM $marksheet ";
                                        $result = mysqli_query($dbConn,$query) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($dbConn));
                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                             $id = $row['id'];
                                             $student_id = $row['student_id'];
                                             $regno = $row['regno'];
                                             $full_name = $row['full_name'];
                                             $t1a1 = $row['t1a1'];
                                             $t1a2 = $row['t1a2'];
                                             $t1a3 = $row['t1a3'];
                                             $t1ex = $row['t1ex'];
                                             $t2a1 = $row['t2a1'];
                                             $t2a2 = $row['t2a2'];
                                             $t2a3 = $row['t2a3'];
                                             $t2ex = $row['t2ex'];
                                             $t3a1 = $row['t3a1'];
                                             $t3a2 = $row['t3a2'];
                                             $t3a3 = $row['t3a3'];
                                             $t3ex = $row['t3ex'];
                                             $marksheet = $marksheet;
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $student_id; ?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $regno; ?></td>
                                          <td><?php echo $full_name; ?></td>
                                          <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ca1" name="ca1" value="<?php echo $t1a1; ?>" />
                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ca2" name="ca2" value="<?php echo $t1a2 ?>" />
                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ca3" name="ca3" value="<?php echo $t1a3; ?>" />
                                          </td>
                                          <td>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ex" name="ex" value="<?php echo $t1ex; ?>" />
                                          </td>

                                           <td>
                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"   id="<?php echo $id; ?>" href="#"  > <i class="fa fa-save"></i> </button>
                                            </div>
                                           </td>
                                           <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="marksheet1"  value="<?php echo $marksheet; ?>" />
                                        </tr>

                                        <?php
                                            echo "<script>
                                                $(\"#$id\").click(function(){
                                                    var id = $id;
                                                    var marksheet = $('#marksheet1').val();
                                                    var ca1 = $('#ca1').val();
                                                    var ca2 = $('#ca2').val();
                                                    var ca3 = $('#ca3').val();
                                                    var ex = $('#ex').val();
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                        url: 'update_marksheet.php',
                                                        method: 'post',
                                                        data:{
                                                            id:id,
                                                            marksheet:marksheet,
                                                            ca1:ca1,
                                                            ca2:ca2,
                                                            ca3:ca3,
                                                            ex:ex
                                                        },
                                                        success: function(response){
                                                            alert(response);
                                                            $('#$id').addClass('fa fa-check btn-success');
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                });
                                                </script>";

                                            $sn++;
                                        } 
                                        ?>
                                    </tbody>
```

Comment: You loop will define the id `ca1` and other more than one time, so the script will not work. You can add to all your `id=""` the $id like `id="i{$id}ca1"` and the access it via  `$('#i{$id}ca1').val();`, have a try.

Comment: tnks man, that was helpful